# How can I upload folder and files both from same input type?

Tags: html

I am using a form where I can upload both, a file or full folder. I am using following code:

```
<html>
  <input type = "file" id = "file" name = "files[]" multiple/>
  <input id="file" type=file multiple webkitdirectory directory>
</html>
```

With first input, I can upload file but not folder and with 2nd input, I can upload folder but not file. But I want to be able to upload both with same input.

Please tell me what is the exact code by which I can upload both file and folder in single click.

Comment: Both is not possible up to date.

Comment: off-topic: remove spaces between attributes, values and `=`... so `id="file"` instead of `id = "file"`

Answer (score 3):

As I'm writing this, this is not possible with pure HTML, unless you use some plugin like Flash then maybe it's possible.

1 file upload:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Multiple files upload (but must be in same folder):

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

1 folder upload (Note: not all browsers may support this):

```
<input type="file" name="file" webkitdirectory directory>
```

Multiple folders upload maybe not possible currently.

Here is a trick that might work (but I didn't test it): You can drag and drop file(s) and folder(s) directly in the input field, for example from your desktop to the browser's input. Try selecting files AND folders and drog-n-drop them in your input field, but I don't know if they will be uploaded correctly to the server.

**EDIT:**

Just tested that trick, it didn't work :/

Comment: What is the benefit of folder upload if we can't get folders on server side?

Comment: The drag&drop thing should work (you can [test it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932586/uploading-directory-and-maintainign-structure-through-javascript-and-html5/47935286#47935286)). But what is not possible though is to have the dialog for both directories and single/multiple files. I am not entirely sure, but I think it's even an OS restriction (at least on osX).