# How just select directory not file?

Tags: javascript, html

I using js to create my form, my problem is how to just select  `directory`, **not** `file`?

Belows is my coding:

```js
const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
const customBtn = document.getElementById("custom-button");
const customTxt = document.getElementById("custom-text");

customBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  realFileBtn.click();
});

realFileBtn.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (realFileBtn.value) {
    customTxt.innerHTML = realFileBtn.value;
  } else {
    customTxt.innerHTML = "No file chosen, yet.";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="real-file" hidden="hidden" />
<button type="button" id="custom-button">CHOOSE A FILE</button>
<span id="custom-text">No file chosen, yet.</span>
```

Below is my output:

[image: Output 1]

Actually I want the output not to select the `file`, just **select** the `folder`, because the next step I need store file in this folder directory.

If success the output is folder directory name is:

> C:\Staff Import Folder\Source

Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html5/Javascript - How to get the Selected folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718769/html5-javascript-how-to-get-the-selected-folder-name)

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page

Answer (score 2):

In newest browsers, you can select a directory content with the [`webkitdirectory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) attribute of the <input type="file"> element, as being defined by [Files and Directories entries API](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/), but I fear this will be deceptive to you since it will only select all the files in this directory (and its sub-folders). There is currently no way to navigate this directory from here.

We should be able to navigate such directory, by looking at the `webkitEntries` IDL attribute, but currently browsers only populate this from a drop event. You can see a demo in [this Q.A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932586/uploading-directory-and-maintainign-structure-through-javascript-and-html5/47935286#47935286).

```js
inp.onchange = (e) => {
  console.log( inp.webkitEntries ); // []
  console.log( [...inp.files].map( file => file.name ) );
};
```

```html
<input type="file" webkitdirectory id="inp">
```

But even then, while you'll be able to *navigate* that directory, you still won't be able to set anything on the FileSystem. Web scripts simply don't have the authorization to write anything on the disk, except in sand-boxed areas like IndexedDB.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

```js
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById("listing");
  let files = event.target.files;

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    output.appendChild(item);
  };
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" webkitdirectory multiple />
<ul id="listing"></ul>
```

Comment: ``webkitdirectory`` is still not standardized, it will not work in many browsers.

Comment: and it only retrieves directory content.